# Implementing an efficient Pair-Matching Algorithm

Tags: algorithm, theory, matching

Suppose that I have two lists of objects and I would like to match every object in list one with every object in list two.

This would probably be the algorithm that one would immediately  come up with.

```
for( it_1=list_1.begin() ; it_1!=list_1.end() ; it_1++ )
  {
      for( it_2=list_2.begin() ; it_2!=list_2.end() ; it_2++ )
      {
          //now match 
           match(*it_1,*it_2);
      }

  }
```

I wonder if there is any better way of doing this. This requires O(n1*n2), where n1 and n2 are the length of list_1 and list_2, respectively.

Comment: What does your `match` function do?

Comment: The actual algorithm I am dealing with is not exactly the same as this one. So the body inside these nested for loops is a lot more complicated than this one. But the idea is the same, that is, matching every object in List1 with every in List 2.

The match function could be just a simple addition or anything. Just ignore it. The focus should be on the loops and how to match.

Comment: If `match` can be anything, then this algorithm (ignoring the typos in the outer loop increment) is asymptotically optimal. To improve it, you need to have knowledge of what the code inside the loop is doing.

Comment: I see. The only way to improve this should be to parallelize the loops then. 

Thanks for your  answer, larsmans.

Comment: std::for_each and a generic functor can be of help?

Comment: another way to make this algorithm faster is to preorder the elements with a given function and then exploit the ordering to reduce loop iterations...

Comment: @linello, why is that the case? I think it should be of O(n1*n2) complexity as well.

Every element in list 1 must be matched with every in list 2. I cannot see any benefit from reordering elements.

Comment: @takwing: You can reduce 2d to 1d with space filling curves. That's a reorder of the elements and can help the matching function.

Comment: @Chiyou, can you direct me to where I can learn more on this transformation?

Comment: http://blog.notdot.net/2009/11/Damn-Cool-Algorithms-Spatial-indexing-with-Quadtrees-and-Hilbert-Curves

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can make use of multi threading here by diving the list1 to 2 or 3 parts depending on the size and efficiency u r looking for , and run the match algorithm in each thread with list2 and collating the results back to the caller.

See if it helps..